# Upload of application bundle failed with error: EISDIR: illegal operation on directory (Elastic Beanstalk deploy VSTS)

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-deployment

I am trying to set up a CICD pipeline using Visual Studio > Visual Studio Team Services > Elastic Beanstalk Create version.

I have been able to check in my code OK, and kick off my build pipeline which contains the following step in place of 'publish artefact':

"Create Elastic Beanstalk Revision:"

This step is attached to an AWS IAM User with Administrator privileges. This step fails when I try to run my pipeline to deploy the ASP.NET application (Webforms, so not Core) via this method.

The error output is as follows:

> 2018-07-30T04:46:22.7765736Z ##[section]Starting: Create Elastic
>   Beanstalk Revision: Sparky 2018-07-30T04:46:22.7771363Z
>   ============================================================================== 2018-07-30T04:46:22.7771634Z Task         : AWS Elastic Beanstalk
>   Create Version 2018-07-30T04:46:22.7771964Z Description  : Create an
>   application revision for deployment to an environment.
>   2018-07-30T04:46:22.7772192Z Version      : 1.0.21
>   2018-07-30T04:46:22.7772403Z Author       : Amazon Web Services
>   2018-07-30T04:46:22.7772908Z Help         : Please refer to [AWS
>   Elastic Beanstalk User
>   Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)
>   for more details on deploying applications with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
>   2018-07-30T04:46:22.7773336Z
>   ============================================================================== 2018-07-30T04:46:23.2641747Z ac747f99-1789-4d43-86c5-c8283d1a72c0
>   exists true 2018-07-30T04:46:23.2671026Z Deployment type set to aspnet
>   2018-07-30T04:46:24.8994140Z Determine S3 bucket
>   elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-2-153247006570 to store application
>   bundle 2018-07-30T04:46:24.9038683Z ***Upload of application bundle
>   failed with error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read*** {
>   Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
>   2018-07-30T04:46:24.9047409Z Uploading application bundle D:\a\1\a to
>   object Sparky/a-cicd_test.zip in bucket
>   elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-2-153247006570
>   2018-07-30T04:46:24.9048878Z ##[error]Error: EISDIR: illegal operation
>   on a directory, read 2018-07-30T04:46:24.9053846Z     at Error
>   (native) errno: -4068, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }
>   2018-07-30T04:46:24.9172250Z ##[section]Finishing: Create Elastic
>   Beanstalk Revision: Sparky

I could find very little (pretty much no) results online about this error. I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any ideas anyone? I know it's not IAM permissions as I am using ADMIN for the AWS User just for testing.

EDIT: Added image of build definition. (Note, I don't really know how to use version label output variables so just put something there, but I don't think that's the issue, this failure is something else entirely. I'm just following online example/tutorials for a basic deployment)

[image]

The build extension is https://aws.amazon.com/vsts/ and looking back over my screenshot and the instructions I was following here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploying-net-web-applications-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-visual-studio-team-services/ I just realised a mistake! I didn't specify the file name in the web deploy archive.

I changed

$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

To

$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\SparkIdeaGenerator.zip

And the build succeeded! However, clearly I didn't understand the purpose of this build task, as it has only created an application revision in AWS, it hasn't actually deployed the updated code. This isn't much good, as I still need to go into the console and click 'Deploy'. This doesn't seem ideal. Here's what I mean:

[image]

Clearly I didn't understand the limits of this build task. I thought it would create the revision and deploy the code. It doesn't. There is only one other Elastic Beanstalk build task available in the toolset I downloaded, which is 'create application'. I don't want this, as I already have the application present, I Just want to update it. I will take a look further into this, as I need that full end-to-end automation, commit code, run build, deploy code, update site.

I will however mark the question as answered, as I have solved this specific question/error by specifically referencing a .zip with the package name of the solution itself.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your build definition? Is `Create Elastic Beanstalk Revision` a custom build task?

Comment: Hi there Cece, screenshot added, also the build task is not custom, it is a standard build task as a part of the AWS Toolkit for visual studio team services. I have confirmed that the application name that I have referenced exists in AWS as I have previously deployed to it fine using AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. I also know that the AWS credentials are OK as I have temporarily given them Admin privileges for the sake of testing. I can also confirm that the S3 bucket being used exists (and contains revisions of the code from earlier deployments via Visual Studio directly).

Comment: Which build extension did you use? Could you provide the name or link? Which example/tutorials did you refer to?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me again Cece, apologies for not including this information within my original post. The build extension is https://aws.amazon.com/vsts/ and looking back over my screenshot and the instructions I was following here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploying-net-web-applications-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-visual-studio-team-services/ I just realised a mistake! I didn't specify the file name in the web deploy archive. I did this and build succeeded, however it only created a revision of the site, it doesn't seem to have deployed it. Hmm..

Comment: I will update my post to show what I mean.

Comment: Do you use the correct task? It seems you should use `AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Application` task.

Comment: hi guys .. we are suffering from this as well as the time of writing this commit. seems like an internal issue in the vsts itself. Any update on this plz @CeceDong-MSFT?

Comment: Guys no update on this till now ? it's clearly an integration issue from Microsoft/Amazon teams. Plz help

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I solved this issue by changing the folder pointing to the web deploy archive to include the name of the solution, e.g. $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\SparkIdeaGenerator.zip. This solved my issue. The remaining problem was I wasn't using the correct task for actually deploying the application via Elastic Beanstalk but that's unrelated to the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

The process is defined in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/tutorial-eb.html
It states that you use the zip file name along with the $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), like what was identified above.
This does appear to fix the issue.